# Syncing problems with multiple flvs

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, flv, synchronization

Is it possible to sync flv videos? I'm playing a few videos simultaneously, and they are inconsistently out of sync. If I add a button that seeks all of the videos to 0, they may or may not be in sync. When they're out of sync, it's only a fraction of a second, but for this application, a fraction of a second is very noticeable. Can we get frame-accurate syncs?

For reference, here's the stripped-down code to play the vids. (It's just a standard netstream call)

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);

var ns1:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
vid_1.attachNetStream(ns1);
ns1.play("vid1.flv");
ns1.pause();
ns1.seek(0);
ns1.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netstat);

var ns2:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
vid_2.attachNetStream(ns2);
ns2.play("vid2.flv");
ns2.pause();
ns2.seek(0);
ns2.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netstat);

function netstat(stats:NetStatusEvent) {
 //trace(stats.info.code);
}
var netClient:Object = new Object();
netClient.onMetaData = function(meta:Object){
              //trace(meta.duration);
      };

ns1.client = netClient;
ns2.client = netClient;

ns1.resume();
ns2.resume();
```

And I have a button:

```
btn_play.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
 ns1.seek(0.0);
 ns2.seek(0.0);
};
```

Clicking the button restarts the videos, sometimes in sync, sometimes not.

Any way to consistently get them in sync?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might consider pausing both videos until the "NetStream.Seek.Notify" status event has fired off for both videos. It fires when the video has finished seeking to its intented timecode.